# How to get sentiment via stanford corenlp interactive shell?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, pexpect, interactive-shell

[image: Interactive shell with all annotators including sentiment]I have been trying to get the *sentiment value from the stanford corenlp*, but it seems in the interactive shell, the sentiment is not given as an output.

I have specified the *annotators* using the command given in the official website.

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref, sentiment
```

Also, when i tried for getting just the sentiment, then at first asked for other annotators, after providing i didn't give any output at all.

I am getting the interactive shell in both the cases. Like - NLP>
But, there is no sign of sentiment - positive or negative.

Also, if we use the sentimentPipeline instead of nlp.pipeline. It gives the sentiment. Is there any way i can get via the interactive shell or if possible is there any way we can use sentimentPipeline with pexpect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: old_version]I was using the older version of Stanford corenlp (3.4.1), but in the recent version (3.5.1), it gives the sentiment.[image: new_version]